# Как вывести уникальные элементы многомерного массива?

Tags: javascript

Есть многомерный массив:

```
var pl_name = [
        ['Красноярский край, Красноярск', [56.00473,92.827998], 'Лукъяненко Сергей', 'Лабиринт отражений', '450'],
        ['Красноярский край, Березовка', [56.029293,93.11639], 'Лукъяненко Сергей', 'Лабиринт отражений', '450'],
        ['Красноярский край, Красноярск', [56.00473,92.827998], 'Джоан Роулинг', 'Гарри Поттер', '420'],
        ['Красноярский край, Березовка', [56.029293,93.11639], 'Джоан Роулинг', 'Гарри Поттер', '420'],
        ['Красноярский край, Красноярск', [56.00473,92.827998], 'Лукъяненко Сергей', 'Лабиринт отражений', '450'],
        ['Красноярский край, Березовка', [56.029293,93.11639], 'Лукъяненко Сергей', 'Лабиринт отражений', '450'],
        ['Красноярский край, Красноярск', [56.00473,92.827998], 'Джоан Роулинг', 'Гарри Поттер', '420'],
        ['Красноярский край, Березовка', [56.029293,93.11639], 'Джоан Роулинг', 'Гарри Поттер', '420'],
        ['Красноярский край, Красноярск', [56.00473,92.827998], 'Лукъяненко Сергей', 'Ночной дозор', '540'],
        ['Красноярский край, Солонцы', [56.0686,92.826718], 'Лукъяненко Сергей', 'Ночной дозор', '540']
    ];
```

Нужно, чтобы повторяющиеся элементы попали во второй массив только один раз. Вот так:

```
var places = [
        ['Красноярский край, Красноярск', [56.00473,92.827998], 'Лукъяненко Сергей', 'Лабиринт отражений', '450'],
        ['Красноярский край, Березовка', [56.029293,93.11639], 'Лукъяненко Сергей', 'Лабиринт отражений', '450'],
        ['Красноярский край, Красноярск', [56.00473,92.827998], 'Джоан Роулинг', 'Гарри Поттер', '420'],
        ['Красноярский край, Березовка', [56.029293,93.11639], 'Джоан Роулинг', 'Гарри Поттер', '420'],
        ['Красноярский край, Красноярск', [56.00473,92.827998], 'Лукъяненко Сергей', 'Ночной дозор', '540'],
        ['Красноярский край, Солонцы', [56.0686,92.826718], 'Лукъяненко Сергей', 'Ночной дозор', '540']
    ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача странная, но:

```js
let pl_name = [
  ['Красноярский край, Красноярск', [56.00473, 92.827998], 'Лукъяненко Сергей', 'Лабиринт отражений', '450'],
  ['Красноярский край, Березовка', [56.029293, 93.11639], 'Лукъяненко Сергей', 'Лабиринт отражений', '450'],
  ['Красноярский край, Красноярск', [56.00473, 92.827998], 'Джоан Роулинг', 'Гарри Поттер', '420'],
  ['Красноярский край, Березовка', [56.029293, 93.11639], 'Джоан Роулинг', 'Гарри Поттер', '420'],
  ['Красноярский край, Красноярск', [56.00473, 92.827998], 'Лукъяненко Сергей', 'Лабиринт отражений', '450'],
  ['Красноярский край, Березовка', [56.029293, 93.11639], 'Лукъяненко Сергей', 'Лабиринт отражений', '450'],
  ['Красноярский край, Красноярск', [56.00473, 92.827998], 'Джоан Роулинг', 'Гарри Поттер', '420'],
  ['Красноярский край, Березовка', [56.029293, 93.11639], 'Джоан Роулинг', 'Гарри Поттер', '420'],
  ['Красноярский край, Красноярск', [56.00473, 92.827998], 'Лукъяненко Сергей', 'Ночной дозор', '540'],
  ['Красноярский край, Солонцы', [56.0686, 92.826718], 'Лукъяненко Сергей', 'Ночной дозор', '540']
];

let result = [];

pl_name.forEach((el, index) => {
    let existsInResult = false;
  
    result.forEach(el2 => {
        if (el <= el2 && el >= el2)
            existsInResult = true;
    });
  
    if (!existsInResult)
        result.push(el);
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Для данного случая подходит, но как общее решение будет натыкаться на множество пограничных глюков. Например, будет считаться равным `[['1'], '']` и `[1, null]`.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty а ещё могут быть пустые массивы, не массивы вовсе, пони, единороги, и другие пограничные глюки.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty Давайте не усложнять жизнь себе и другим и не придумывать за остальных что есть или чего нет.  Есть конкретный пример, конкретная задача, остальное - не имеет смысла воображать

Comment: Ок. Я не спорю, это просто на всякий случай, если кто потом захочет использовать как общее решение.

Comment: А. Хорошо. Правда я бы скорее отнёс такой комментарий, если бы вопрос был в целом "как сравнить два массива". Но ок)

Comment: «Нам не дано предугадать, как наше слово отзовётся» :)

Answer (score 1):

Если порядок элементов постоянный и там только строки и числа, можно ещё так:

```js
const pl_name = [
  ['Красноярский край, Красноярск', [56.00473, 92.827998], 'Лукъяненко Сергей', 'Лабиринт отражений', '450'],
  ['Красноярский край, Березовка', [56.029293, 93.11639], 'Лукъяненко Сергей', 'Лабиринт отражений', '450'],
  ['Красноярский край, Красноярск', [56.00473, 92.827998], 'Джоан Роулинг', 'Гарри Поттер', '420'],
  ['Красноярский край, Березовка', [56.029293, 93.11639], 'Джоан Роулинг', 'Гарри Поттер', '420'],
  ['Красноярский край, Красноярск', [56.00473, 92.827998], 'Лукъяненко Сергей', 'Лабиринт отражений', '450'],
  ['Красноярский край, Березовка', [56.029293, 93.11639], 'Лукъяненко Сергей', 'Лабиринт отражений', '450'],
  ['Красноярский край, Красноярск', [56.00473, 92.827998], 'Джоан Роулинг', 'Гарри Поттер', '420'],
  ['Красноярский край, Березовка', [56.029293, 93.11639], 'Джоан Роулинг', 'Гарри Поттер', '420'],
  ['Красноярский край, Красноярск', [56.00473, 92.827998], 'Лукъяненко Сергей', 'Ночной дозор', '540'],
  ['Красноярский край, Солонцы', [56.0686, 92.826718], 'Лукъяненко Сергей', 'Ночной дозор', '540']
];

const result = Array.from(
  new Set(pl_name.map(_ => JSON.stringify(_))),
  _ => JSON.parse(_),
);

console.log(result);
```